# Piping stdout to gstreamer

Tags: video, gstreamer, h.264

Good Day,

I am trying to get gst-launch (gstreamer) to get the input from stdout. Most of the examples on the net are about either reading from file or reading from device. Does anyone know an example pipeline?

```
filesrc location="lowframe.h264"
```

or

```
device=/dev/video0
```

Is there one that would read from stdout?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a GStreamer element called `fdsrc` that allows you to read from (already open) file descriptors.
`stdin` is basically `fd 0` (on POSIX systems like Linux/Mac; see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)), so you can simply use something like the following launch line:

```
curl http://example.com:8000/stream1.ogg ! gst-launch fdsrc fd=0 ! decodebin ! autoaudiosink
```

Another way would be to use `filesrc` and read from `/dev/stdin` on systems that support it, e.g.:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=/dev/stdin ! decodebin ! autoaudiosink < /path/to/file.mp3
```

**/edit** found out about the `fdsrc` method (which seems to be the better solution to this problem)

Comment: Google brings me first here for the reverse problem: **redirecting gstreamer output to stdout**. The logically solution is to add `! filesink location=/dev/stdout` to the end of the pipeline.

Comment: this does not work at all, curl complaining about displaying binary on screen. and with > pipe symbol nothing at all:curl http://192.168.1.174:8080/video > gst-launch fdsrc fd=0  ! decodebin ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1D